# Do you use the Djinn you attain from the Sibittis ability' immediately?

Tags: five-tribes

The Djinn Sibittis has an ability which states:

> Draw the top 3 Djinns from the top of the Djinns pile; keep 1, discard the 2 others.

In the rules under Sacred Places it has a point which states:

> You can use the special powers of any Djinn you took right away, without waiting; however if there is a cost, you must be able to pay that cost now.

Would a player possibly be able to trigger 2 Djinn abilities using Sibittis? The first being Sibittis, the second being the Djinn you attain using Sibittis ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the special power of a Djinn using Sibittis, yes, by the text you quote. If you mean can you use Sibittis's ability twice in one turn, then no.

This is also true without invoking Sibittis. If you have multiple Djinn cards, you can use each one once per turn.

Details from [this thread on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1221604/activating-djinn).

> Each djinn can be used once per turn in any order you want. If u dont want to use them all u dont have to. Just cant use the same one twice.

> Q: If you buy Sibittis, you can use him straight away (that's fine). But, can you use the djinn you get from his ability immediately as well?
> A: If it has an activation cost, yes. The rules make no distinction.

> There is no limit on the number of djinns you can use in your turn, as long as you can pay the activation cost. Nothing in the rules suggests otherwise.

Comment: I guess your 2nd quote answers my question. So if the player attains a new Djinn using Sibittis ability, they're able to use the ability of the new Djinn as well. This means that a play may be able to use the ability of 2 different Djinn in one turn. I've updated the last line of my question for clarification purposes.

Comment: Right. This is true with or without Sibittis: you are always free to use each Djinn you have (once each).